# How do I fix a low spot under vinyl plank flooring?

Tags: flooring

There is a low area right beside my island where two planks abut. One of the planks at its edge where they abut can be pushed down with the weight of a chair or a foot. It is a small area maybe 2 x 1 inch and I would like to be able to inject something that would support that small area.

What can I inject under this area to support the end of this plank?

Comment: How deep is the low spot?

Comment: i use melted candle wax in a syringe kept in hot water until application. In also like to pre-heat the floor with a hair dryer or hot air gun to ensure fill, but it probably doesn't matter if you only built a support island instead of flooding the perimeter....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your floor is floating and you don't want the floor to bond to the subfloor, you should use a high flex caulking and inject that into the hollow under the boards. DAP EXTREME Stretch Caulking or Big Stretch caulking are good choices.

The general technique is drill a hole, use a turkey baster or some plunge type injector, fill it with caulking and use it to fill the low area of the planks.  You can use a soldering iron and some of the shavings from a vinyl based floor to seal the hole (practice on a scrap board first) or use wax to hide the hole afterwards.

I like this guys technique:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MGA3cyLJBc

Comment: Please include _some_ amount of description of the technique in the video. As soon as the video is taken down (that _never_ happens </sarcasm>) that part of the answer becomes useless.